# Converting file formats

Tags: python, unix, formatting

I have the following sample file (a), I want to convert it to sample file (b) using Unix or Python commands. My actual file is much larger (several GB).

(a):

```
Sol_00000001    H2O2    KNMO4   NaCl
Sol_00000002    NaCl    NaCl
Sol_00000003    KOCl    NHO2    NHO2
Sol_00000004    H2O2
Sol_00000005    KNMO4
Sol_00000006    NaCl
Sol_00000007    KOCl
Sol_00000008    NHO2
Sol_00000009    H2O2    NaCl    KOCl    NHO2    KNMO4
```

(b):

```
NaCl    Sol_00000001    Sol_00000002    Sol_00000006    Sol_00000009
KOCl    Sol_00000003    Sol_00000007    Sol_00000009
H2O2    Sol_00000001    Sol_00000004    Sol_00000009
NHO2    Sol_00000003    Sol_00000008    Sol_00000009
KNMO4   Sol_00000001    Sol_00000005    Sol_00000009
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Comment: What have you tried?  What (built-in) Python data structure is most appropriate?  The basic task is simple.  It doesn't even appear as though you need to sort the chemical codes in the output.

Comment: Hi @JonathanLeffler, thank you for your response. I've tried some shell scripting (Unix) to see if I could cluster the solutions as in file (b). I'm knew to coding (only began within the fast few weeks) so any advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tagged this with Python; does that mean you are learning Python?  Or are you learning shell scripting and a solution using, say, `awk` or Perl would be acceptable?  I re-emphasize the questions in my previous comment.  What have you tried — and which data structure is most appropriate for storing the information?

Comment: I'm attempting to learn Python, I've started a few basic online exercises and I'm taking a series of workshops in the coming weeks. An awk or Perl would be most acceptable. I have written a shell script which I hoped would take a chemical at random print all the solutions that come after it (as in b) then remove the chemical from the database and reiterate until the database was empty, unless I'm mistaken an array would be perfect, as long as (b) was the output. Thanks.

Comment: *I attempted to use perl, awk, comm, echo and grep to construct the shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source data is in ch_source.txt, this script will create ch_dst.txt in the format above from it.  But it will use a lot of memory in the process, because all the data has to be stored before the output file can be created.

This is a Python 2 script.  A Python 3 script would have to use bytes in order to be space efficient, and would use `items` instead of `iteritems`.

With a little more research, you will figure out how to pass filenames on the command line rather than hard-coding them into the script.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2

import collections

def translate(srcf, dstf):
    by_chem = collections.defaultdict(list)

    with open(srcf, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            values = line.split()
            if not values:
                continue
            soln = values.pop(0)
            for chem in values:
                by_chem[chem].append(soln)
    with open(dstf, 'wb') as f:
        for chem, solns in sorted(by_chem.iteritems()):
            f.write('%s\t%s\n' % (chem, '\t'.join(solns)))

translate('ch_source.txt', 'ch_dst.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll offer 3 solutions — in Awk, Perl, and Python 2.

#### Awk

This is a shell script that runs `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) list[$i] = list[$i] "  " $1 }
     END { for (i in list) printf "%-7s  %s\n", i, list[i] }' "$@"
```

#### Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %list = ();

while (<>)
{
    my ($chem, @soln) = split;
    push @{$list{$_}}, $chem foreach (@soln);
}

for my $key (sort { lc($a) cmp lc($b) } keys %list)
{
    printf "%-7s  %s\n", $key, join('  ', @{$list{$key}});
}
```

#### Python 2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput

list = {}

for line in fileinput.input():
    bits = line.split()
    for i in range(1, len(bits)):
        if bits[i] not in list:
            list[bits[i]] = []
        list[bits[i]].append(bits[0])

for key in sorted(list.keys(), key = str.lower):
    print "%-7s  %s" % (key, '  '.join(list[key]))
```

#### Example outputs

```
$ sh so.32062773.sh so.32062773.data
NaCl       Sol_00000001  Sol_00000002  Sol_00000002  Sol_00000006  Sol_00000009
H2O2       Sol_00000001  Sol_00000004  Sol_00000009
KNMO4      Sol_00000001  Sol_00000005  Sol_00000009
KOCl       Sol_00000003  Sol_00000007  Sol_00000009
NHO2       Sol_00000003  Sol_00000003  Sol_00000008  Sol_00000009
$ perl so.32062773.pl so.32062773.data
H2O2     Sol_00000001  Sol_00000004  Sol_00000009
KNMO4    Sol_00000001  Sol_00000005  Sol_00000009
KOCl     Sol_00000003  Sol_00000007  Sol_00000009
NaCl     Sol_00000001  Sol_00000002  Sol_00000002  Sol_00000006  Sol_00000009
NHO2     Sol_00000003  Sol_00000003  Sol_00000008  Sol_00000009
$ python so.32062773.py so.32062773.data
H2O2     Sol_00000001  Sol_00000004  Sol_00000009
KNMO4    Sol_00000001  Sol_00000005  Sol_00000009
KOCl     Sol_00000003  Sol_00000007  Sol_00000009
NaCl     Sol_00000001  Sol_00000002  Sol_00000002  Sol_00000006  Sol_00000009
NHO2     Sol_00000003  Sol_00000003  Sol_00000008  Sol_00000009
$
```

The `awk` does not attempt to sort the keys.  It would be feasible to pipe the output to `sort -f` to get the same case-insensitive sorted output as Perl and Python give.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to read each line of the file, split the line into its constituent words, and then record for each molecule what solutions it occurs in.  In python, the most natural data structure for storing this information is a dict.  The keys would be molecules, and the values would be lists of solutions containing the molecule.  Once you've constructed the dict, you just have to write each entry to a file.

This should be more than enough to get you started.  Take a shot at it, and come back with specific questions if you can't get it to work.